# How to use mongoimport in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongoimport

How to load data to MongoDB using Windows PowerShell?

I have installed MongoDB on computer with Windows.
It is in the path:
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\".
I have created required folder \data\db on C drive. I have started mongod.exe and it is running.
I would like to load a CSV file to MongoDB database.

Using `.\mongoimport.exe --help` command, we can notice that in PowerShell to load data to MongoDB, we are not using hyphen-minus but colon.
I have created this code:

```
$params = 'db:', 'db_name',
          'collection:', 'collection_name',
          'type:', 'file_type',
          'file:', 'file_name',
          'headerline'
& "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongoimport.exe" @params
```

and trying to execute it in PowerShell in folder where file is stored.

Error message is displayed:

> error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed
>   try 'mongoimport --help' for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not omit the hyphens from the parameter names, and I'm not sure the colons are valid.

```
$params = '--db', 'db_name',
          '--collection', 'collection_name',
          '--type', 'file_type',
          '--file', 'file_name',
          '--headerline'
& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongoimport.exe' $params
```

I don't think it makes a difference whether you use splatting (`@params`) or regular argument passing (`$params`) in this case.

Comment: Really, really strange. I have found your old post, where I have copied the code and updated to my need. Was not working (was with hyphens). I have removed them, and as I recall I was able to load data, but wasn't able to replicate it :).
This code posted here works ;) with hyphens. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are included as a single item in the array:

```
$params = @(
    'db:db_name',
    'collection:collection_name',
    'type:file_type',
    'file:file_name',
    'headerline'
)

&"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongoimport.exe" @params
```